# Terminal Server default gateway configuration

Tags: configuration, ip-address, gateway, terminal-server

Our Terminal Server (TS) is only accessible on one network, therefore I believe the default gateway has not been set correctly or needs to be updated.

I am looking for the commands in a telnet session to:
1. Review the current configuration of the terminal servers default gateway ip address and, 
2. The command to set it if it needs to be changed.

The TS is a :

> N-Base Xyplex Max Server 1640

I Have reviewed some on line documentation but can't really find a clear solution but I am also not a network tech!

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may come in handy for others:

To set gateway address:

```
ENTER GATEWAY IP ADDRESS [0.0.0.0]:
```

Good instruction manual available [here](http://www.andovercg.com/datasheets/xyplex-maxserver-manual#page128)

Still not sure how to check current gateway setting.